# PHP remote connection to MS SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: php, html, sql-server, netbeans

Im trying to insert into a table remotely. And my database is MS sql server 2016
I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "192.168.50.112");
define("DB_USER", "srv-website");
define("DB_PASS", "Website4JET$");
define("DB_NAME", "FTECHDAS01");
define("TBL_USERS", "[2016_TestJET].[dbo].[Persons]");

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

function addNewUser($id, $name) {
    global $connection;

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." ([PersonID],[LastName]) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";

    return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}
```

but I got always :

**Not Found**

**HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.**

what should I do? and what should change in the remote server !?

Comment: It looks like you didn't even make it to the actual script. Are you sure you are accessing the correct script in your browser? Anyways - you cannot use MySQL functions (like `mysql_connect()`) for MS SQL Server.

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: I think, this error is not related with `PHP`. 404 shows in case the file or resource file not found.

Comment: @RohanKumar it is wired although I am using netbeans